# Foreign key constraint on SailsJS

Tags: database, node.js, relational-database, sails.js, waterline

This is my College model

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {
      name:{
        type:'string',
        required:true
      },
      location:{
            type:'string',
            required:true
        },
        faculties:{
            collection:'faculty',
            via:'college'
        }
  }
};
```

This is my Faculty model

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {
        name:{
            type:'string',
            required:true
        },
        description:{
            type:'string'
        },
        college:{
            model:'college',
        required:true
        }
        ,
        years:{
            collection:'year',
            via:'faculty'
        }
  }
};
```

My problem is that I can add new `Faculty` with any value in `college` attribute. If I don't have college with 3000 id, I can still add it but `college` attribute won't show up when I list all faculties. How can I prevent it from adding a faculty with invalid college id?

Comment: You have to set a dominant on your association http://www.sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/ORM/Associations/Dominance.html

Comment: To prevent adding faculty with invalid college id you need to implement in your model the beforeValidate method and check your college id manually

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently waterline does not create foreign key constraints in the manner you describe. It only creates the associated field.

You can use a different library instead of Waterline such as Sequelize.js here is a link about how to go about doing that

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sailsjs/ALMxbKfnCIo

If your are using a SQL database you can manally create the foreign key constraint yourself.

Or you can validate the value of college before being set in your faculty model by checking in `beforeValidate()` or `afterValidate()` on your faculty model.